# How to enable a button programmatically when it is disabled in the layout

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-arrayadapter

I'm new to android and I don't know more about it. For practice I was manipulating with spinners, buttons and its attribute.

I have 4 spinners and 1st spinner decides 2nd spinner values and so on. I have a button (android:enabled ="false" in xml) that is located below the 4th spinner and it has a click listener, its click event shows toast about what you select in all spinners.

All spinner's values are in string-array and I want to check and validate all spinners. If any of the spinner is not selected 1st index of array, then button will be enabled otherwise will be disabled.

I have tried many times but not getting expected results. Can anyone help to solve my problem?

Here is my code for button and spinner validation:

```
public boolean isDefaultValue(Spinner spinner){
    if (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0){
        resultButton.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        resultButton.setEnabled(true);
    }
    return false;
}
‎
resultButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (isDefaultValue(sp4)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Country : " + sp1.getSelectedItem().toString() + "\n" +
                        "State : " + sp2.getSelectedItem().toString() + "\n" +
                        "City : " + sp3.getSelectedItem().toString() + "\n" +
                        "Area : " + sp4.getSelectedItem().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
}
 });
```

Comment: **If any of them spinner is not selected 1st index of array** What do you mean by this?

Comment: The array index is always starts at 0. but your code is disabling the button when the selectedItemPosition == 0;.

Comment: Further more you are checking for only one spinner while you want checking for all spinners

Answer (score 0):

Your method `isDefaultValue(Spinner)` would always return a `false` irrespective of button being enabled or not, and hence never raises the toast.

Additionally your description reads:

> If any of them spinner is not selected 1st index of array then button will be enabled

But according to the method `isDefaultValue(Spinner)`, the button will be enabled only when the spinner is not in 1st index of array `(0)`.

Comment: public boolean isDefaultValue(Spinner spinner){
        if (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0){
            resultButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
        return true;
    }       it is still not working, could you please tell me how solve it. my email is mdaanish17@gmail.com

Comment: I noticed one more flaw. Your button is not enabled as per the xml. This would not raise onClick event. Since your method to enable the button lies within the onClick method, this is a deadlock causing the button not to be enabled at all

Comment: sp4.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                if (sp4.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0){
                    resultButton.setEnabled(false);
                }else {
                    resultButton.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        resultButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      Now it is working nice. thank you so much buddy